# Arduino UNO Rx/Tx speaks to itself

Tags: serial

I'm trying to make my chinese arduino (which use a chinese CH340G chip) speaks to itself via serial.
I have wired rx/tx together.

Then, I run the arduino IDE and go to the serial monitor.

When I write a message, the arduino should respond with the exact same message, right ? Actually, when I write a message, the arduino doesn't respond anything...

Comment: Please see for instance http://arduinobasics.blogspot.se/2012/07/arduino-basics-simple-arduino-serial.html

Comment: please re-read my question, I don't want to use any software, I have put a physical jumper between rx and tx pin

Comment: You cannot use the same serial port to have the Arduino speak to the computer **and** speak to itself.

Comment: well in fact I have read that the arduino uno only have 1 serial port and that this port is shared between the computer and the serial pin on the arduino... Isn't that right ?

Comment: This will depend on the bootloader and which state it leaves the port at.

Comment: could you be more precise? talk to me like I'm 5 ;)

Comment: is there a sketch running on the board (blink?)

Comment: no, just an empty sketch

Comment: @MikaelPatel: The Uno bootloader (optiboot) leaves pretty much everything in the initial, after-reset state: USART disabled and its pins as high-impedance inputs.

Comment: I checked the init() and it will puts PORTB to all input. So that is not the issue. The RX might require a pullup when in loop-back?

Comment: TX is an output (DDD1 overridden) when the UART transmitter is active, so no need to pull up.

Comment: Found this Russian web-page that had schematics for an UNO with CH340G. A closer look shows that there are a few 1K ohm resistors in the way (voltage divider for the RX/TX LEDs). http://jarick.com.ua/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/25-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-arduino-uno-r3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-atmega328-%D0%B8-ch340g.html

Comment: `I have put a physical jumper between rx and tx pin` - to clarify, you jumpered together digital pins 0 and 1? Not some other place?

Comment: yes exactly http://i.imgur.com/ZtG2IEl.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mikael Patel pointed out in his answer, you have set up a voltage divider. Mikael has thoughtfully provided a schematic of the clone Uno, where the relevant part is here:

[image: Clone schematic]

---

### Equivalent circuit

If you jumper together pins D0 and D1 (Rx and Tx) on the Uno effectively you have made this circuit:

[image: Loop-back voltage divider]

---

### Testing

If I set up this with a function generator, I get this result:

[image: Loop-back scope results]

You can see that for a square-wave input of 0 to 5V, we only get an output of 2.16 to 5V.

---

### What is LOW?

Now looking at the datasheet for the DC characteristics we see:

[image: DC characteristics]

For an input to register as LOW it has to be no higher than `0.3 * Vcc = 0.3 * 5`. Thus the voltage cannot be higher than 1.5V. Since we are measuring 2.16V, that will not count as a LOW.

Now admittedly that is for the Atmega328P and not the CH340G, but it will probably have similar characteristics.

I found a datasheet for the CH340G, and that shows even stricter requirements for a LOW signal:

[image: CH340G datasheet]

---

### Official Uno

Comparing to the official Uno circuit:

[image: Uno schematic]

You will note there that the indicator LEDs are on a different circuit, and thus do not form a voltage divider.

---

### The Maths

The clone Uno circuit above can be re-arranged like this:

[image: Re-arranged circuit]

Given that the LEDs have a voltage drop of 1.86V (measured in practice, and about right for the red LEDs I am using) then effectively we have the resistors R1 and R2 connected to 3.14V.

Since they are in parallel they are effectively 500 ohms.

Now using the formula for voltage dividers:

```
1000 / (1000 + 500) * (5 - 1.86) = 2.09V
```

This is close enough to the observed result. I didn't check each resistor to make sure it was exactly in spec.

I don't think R4 affects the results because it is effectively "floating".

Comment: Great job, Nick! You filled in the blanks and added yet a level of engineering (again). Thanks! Hope others appreciates your knowledge sharing.

Comment: Thanks, @MikaelPatel. There is one thing I'm not happy with, I can't make the maths work out. I am measuring a voltage drop of 1.86V over the LEDs with the 1k resistor.

Comment: If I remove the D2 LED then I measure 1.567V which agrees with: `1000 / 2000 * (5 - 1.86) = 1.57`

Comment: I think I worked the maths out, see amended answer.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found the below schematics of an Arduino UNO with CH340G. A loop-back is not possible as there is a voltage divider (1K ohm, i.e. RX/TX LED) resistors on the RX and TX line.

[image: UNO with CH340G]

Tested on a Chinese Arduino Uno clone (VISduino) with CH340G and just as you wrote a loop-back does not work. Tested also an Arduino Mega 2560 clone with CH340G and a Duemilanove clone with FTDI. Both these work just fine.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your research :) so it means that a message which come through the RX pin can't go to the usb because of this resistor, right ?

Comment: Nja, if you look at the circuit and add the loop-back connecting pin 0 and pin 1. The TXD signal from the CH340G has to go though 1 K and then back through another 1 K to the RXD on the CH340G. The TTL signal is not low enough after that (my guess).

Comment: My loopback test **does** work.

Comment: @EdgarBonet  Your loopback test on an Arduino Uno clone with CH340G does work?

Comment: No, it's a real Uno, but the RX and TX are wired almost the same as in your clone, with the same 1K resistors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem doing a loopback on an Arduino Uno, but you cannot
use the serial monitor at the same time. I wrote the following test
program, which works as expected:

```cpp
const int LED_PIN = 13;

void setup() {
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    uint8_t data = random();
    Serial.write(data);
    while (!Serial.available()) { /* wait */ }
    if (Serial.read() == data) {

        // Two short pulses = success
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        delay(700);
    } else {

        // One long pulse = failure
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        delay(500);
    }
}
```

There are, however, two caveats with this naive program:

1. the loopback wire has to be removed before uploading
2. after connecting the wire, the Arduino has to be reset to get out of
   the while loop.

Comment: This is loop-back on the Arduino side. I think the OP was referring to loop-back on the USB side. It is a good answer but maybe not the right question.

Comment: yes Mikael Patel is right.

Comment: @MikaelPatel: Oh, now I see your point. Since the OP said he wanted to “_make my chinese arduino speaks to itself_”, it seemed to me he wanted to loop back the Arduino side. I also assumed he did not understand that having two TX talking on the same line cannot work.

Answer (score -1):

[image: capacitor on pin 4]
the capacitor on pin 4 is connected to GND not to +5V

Comment: Not on the schematic provided by Mikael Patel. In any case, this doesn't answer the original question.